# When im trying to getting into a relative path im getting an error startindex cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, string

When im trying to getting into a string arelative path im getting an error startindex cannot be less than zero,What the reason the error's appears?

```
  string relativePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
  relativePath.Remove(relativePath.IndexOf(@"\GameSystem"));
```

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and examine `relativePath` in the debugger.

Answer (score 3):

When indexOf doesn't find the string, it returns -1. If you Remove something at the index -1, you get the error you're talking about. That said, relativePath doesn't contain the string. Just Console out the string you think you have there, or put a debug point at that line, to see what current directory really is.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to add some conditional logic, so you can handle strings that do not contain the desired path segment.  You may want to try:

```
string relativePath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
int position = relativePath.IndexOf(@"\GameSystem");
if (position > 0)
{
    relativePath.Remove(position);
}
else
{
    //handle condition rather than throw "start index cannot be less than zero"
}
```